# JQuery Add a Button in a Table Row

Tags: jquery, button

I want to add a button who will edit the row in the table. My code is:

```
$("#tabprincipal tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON("carrega_usuarios.php?vPagina=" + 0+ "&vQtdeLinhas=" + 10,function(data){
    $.each(data.users, function(i,user){
    var newRow =
    "<tr>"
    +"<td>"+user.ID+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.USER+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.GROUP+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.NUMBER+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.STATE+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.BIRTH+"</td>"
    +"<td> <button id='but1' class='botaoadd'>hello </button> </td>"
    +"</tr>" ;
    $(newRow).appendTo("#tabprincipal tbody");
    });
    });
```

But the button doesn't appear in the table cell.

Comment: if all the other cells are there, no reason the button shouldn't be also based just on code shown. Note that ID's can't be repeated in page but that won't cause a display issue

Comment: Are the other cells displaying? Note also `id='but1'` is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html).

Comment: but if i dont use the id..just to know... my problem is how to load the table using the php and put these buttons to edit or delete the item in the database...

Comment: Very easy to traverse a row using class to assign click event to for those buttons. Still not clear if the other parts of row are showing up and not the buttons

Comment: Also another hint `<tr data-user_id="'+user.ID+'">`. 3 lines of code for button clcik event can have that row id

Comment: Charlietfl the other rows are showing normally...only the button dont appear..

Comment: are you sure it's not a css problem? You can't see it in the live html in browser dev tools inspector? Seems very strange unless some other code is doing something to it

Comment: charlietfl could be a css problem but the strange is that a simple text appears..only the button doesnt appear

Comment: try wrapping the button with a <div style="width:100%">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic example of how make dynamic tables with jQuery

HTML

```
<table id="tabprincipal">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRow">Add row</button>
```

CSS

```
.tabrow td div { width: 100%; }

.tabrow.editing td div:first-of-type, 
.tabrow.closed td div:last-of-type  {
    display:none;
}

.tabrow.editing td div:last-of-type, 
.tabrow.closed td div:first-of-type  {
    display:block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("body").on("click","#addRow",function(ev){
        var len = $("#tabprincipal tbody tr").toArray().length;
        var newRow = "<tr class='tabrow closed'>"
        +"<td><div>"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='"+len+"'/></div></td>"
        +"<td><div>A"+len+"</div><div><input type='text' value='A"+len+"'/></div></td>"
        +"<td><div><button class='editRow'>Edit row</button></div><div><button class='saveRow'>Save row</button></div></td>"
        +"</tr>";
        $(newRow).appendTo("#tabprincipal tbody");
    });

    $("body").on("click",".editRow",function(ev){
       $(this).parents(".tabrow").removeClass("closed").addClass("editing");
    });

    $("body").on("click",".saveRow",function(ev){
        var row = $(this).parents(".tabrow");
        // update the cells
        row.find("td").each(function(){
           // new value
           var newVal = $(this).find("input").val();
           $(this).find("div:first").html(newVal);
        });
        row.removeClass("editing").addClass("closed");
    });
});
```

See it on action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b5w53yoo/1/)